# Can you upload a sql script in powerbuilder and output the results?

Tags: sql, upload, powerbuilder

I'm looking to see if there is a way to code PB to upload a sql script and to save the output.  I know how to code PB by writing the sql directly in it, but I want to program it so I can do something like 'click browse', select .sql file, and save the results in a text file.  I've been searching but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell you can open the desired file, read the contents into a string, use the sql string to create a datastore (see SyntaxFromSql method), execute the sql via a retrieve, then save the results with the SaveAs method.